# Magento 2 static file paths incorrect after migration

Tags: magento2, migration, static-content, windows

After manually moving Magento 2.2.4 site to a Windows IIS server, the pages are blank. Only a few lines of HTML is loaded, and I can see in the body tag there is an incorrect static file path:

```
mydomain.com/pub/static/frontend/_view/en_GB/images/loader-2.gif
```

I believe this should be:

```
mydomain.com/pub/static/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/en_GB/images/loader-2.gif
```

**Any idea where the _view is coming from and what might be causing it?**

Cache has been flushed, static files have been generated. I can see static files on the server in correct directories.

I know Magento 2 doesn't officially support Windows, but a fresh install of Magento 2 works fine on this same environment with some small edits.

Comment: Yes, it happen for  Windows server

Comment: Do you know why? Freshly installed Magento 2 works fine on the same Windows server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was likely a very persistent cache issue in our case. Not exactly sure what fixed it, but this sequence got it to work:

- Deleted static files
- Disabled static files signing
- php bin\magento cache:clean
- php bin\magento setup:upgrade
- php bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
- Checked config file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the underlying issue was that the theme wasn't registered properly. There was no entry in the `theme` database table for that theme. The best way to register it is through the `app/etc/config.php` file, see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/config-reference-configphp.html#themes. For example:

```
'themes' => [
  'frontend/Magento/luma' => [
    'parent_id' => 'Magento/blank',
    'theme_path' => 'Magento/luma',
    'theme_title' => 'Magento Luma',
    'is_featured' => '0',
    'area' => 'frontend',
    'type' => '0',
    'code' => 'Magento/luma'
  ]
]
```